# Need Help about this Java Output

Tags: java

Here is a very simple code:

```
  public class Test2 {

public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String a = "hello2"; 
        final String b = "hello";
        String d = "hello";
        String c = b + 2; 
        String e = d + 2;
        System.out.println((a));
        System.out.println((c));
        System.out.println((e));
        System.out.println((a == c));
        System.out.println((a == e));

    }
}
```

And the output is:

```
hello2
hello2
hello2
true
false
```

Please tell me why the last one is 'false'??Thanks

Comment: That is Java string pooling or String interning.

Comment: It returns false, because these two variables point to two different objects. The more interesting question is why `a` and `c` point to the same object. Search here or on Google for "String literal pool" and "interned Strings".

Comment: @Thilo - It is more about *compile-time constants* don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void main(String[] args)  {
        String a = "hello2"; 
        final String b = "hello"; // this will be a compile-time constant. `final String` makes a string compile-time-constant.
        String d = "hello";
        String c = b + 2; // The compiler will replace b+2 by "hello2"
        String e = d + 2; // d is not final. Hence value of b will be calculated at runtime.
        System.out.println((a));
        System.out.println((c));
        System.out.println((e));
        System.out.println((a == c));
        System.out.println((a == e));

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. In your comment "d is not final. Hence value of b will be calculated at runtime.", do you mean e will be calculated at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're comparing objects, not the actual String value. Use `.equals()` to compare String value.

Answer (score 0):

You should compare String values with `equals()` and not `==` operator. `==` compares the references and not the values.